# Access Error when running windows program

Tags: ms-access, database-design, error-handling, winforms

I have a windows form application that uses microsoft access for the database on the backend.

When I run that application I get an error that says access is not installed on the computer.  I thought that if I included the reference that it will be included with what I release so the user would not have to have access installed.

How do I include the Access Runtime to be distributed/installed when my application is installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to use the MS Access Runtime or direct the user to download a trial version of MS Office.

[MS Access Runtime 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=d9ae78d9-9dc6-4b38-9fa6-2c745a175aed&displaylang=en)

I tried it out and the app works.  If their is a better option I would like to know.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried downloading the latest [MDAC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=6c050fe3-c795-4b7d-b037-185d0506396c&displaylang=en) release, if your application is only connecting to an Access DataStore, the local machine requires the drivers to make the connection.

Comment: Are you under the impression that the lasted MDAC installs the Access Runtime? If not, what are you intending to suggest the most recent MDAC would address?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides instructions for [how to deploy an Access Runtime Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb501030.aspx). Is there something about those that doesn't fit your scenario?